# How apache server handles session?

Tags: php, apache

Please tell me how apache server store each logged user's session details.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Session Works?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954879/how-session-works)

Comment: Do not ask the same question twice. You have got your answer already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never heard of Apache storing any session details.
Apache is HTTP demon and HTTP is stateless protocol, with no session support.

You're probably talking of some language emulates stateful connection, using cookie or query string to pass a session identifier.

Comment: Correct, but he tagged the question php5 :)

Comment: well, it's possible duplicate then

Answer (score 0):

Basically in PHP Sessions, the server will use eithers cookies or URL rewriting.

- If cookies are enabled, it will store
  the sessionID in a cookie.
- If cookies are disabled, it will pass
  the sessionID using a parameters
  (GET) by appending forms with a
  hidden elements and links with the
  ID.

Answer (score 0):

PHP stores session data as text files on disk. The browser is then assigned a cookie which identifies which session that belongs to that browser.