# Maintaining session for a login

Tags: http

I was going through `http` wiki page and get to know that `http` is a `stateLess` protocol.
Every network transaction is not dependent on previous  transaction. How a site(fb,google etc) maintain the session weather a user is logged-in or not using http.

Sorry if my question is below level.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954879/how-session-works

Answer (score 0):

By storing session variables, in PHP:

```
$_SESSION['var']
```