# How sessions are identified for user on server

Tags: php, session

Hi i am a php programmer. 
I am asked a question in interview that sessions are stored on client side in browsers / cookie files on client's computer then how server identifies that i m the same user who is logged in from my own PC and I must be shown only that information that belongs to me?
Please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954879/how-session-works

Answer (score 4):

When you login in system (*OR session started*), unique session id created and it usually stored in a **cookie**. that will identify your browser.

The server then uses this **session id** to fetch the data from the server.

Answer (score 3):

`SESSION` is stored at server side, not at client side.

`SESSION` stored `PHPSESSID` at client side as `COOKIE` for identifying respective user.

Answer (score 1):

Session are stored on **server side**.
and every time login session generate a **unique session id**.
the session id server identifies the user.
**$_SESSION** is session variable.

Answer (score 0):

The $_SESSION variable is stored at the server, with a corresponding session_id, generated when the session is started. At the client side, a cookie is stored with that exact same session_id. This way the browser can identify to the server, and the server can release the correct info stored in $_SESSION for this session/user.

Answer (score 0):

- sessions are initiated with [`session_start()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php). If the actual session has no alloacted unique session id, php generates one and sends it with the response to the client. The browser stores the session id either as cookie (if allowed) `PHPSESSID` or if not you have to create every link with the query param `?PHPSESSID=uniquesessionid`. Otherwise no consistent session is possible
- With every request the session cookie (if allowed) or the query param is send. PHP identifies with this session id the data stored on the server side, and you have access trough the `$_SESSION` array. So you can store a username or user id in the session array. For every session id, the session array is unique. You can access only the session you got provided from the browser.
- on most servers the session is stored on the filesystem under the path configured in `session.save_path`. The filename is usually `sess_uniquesessionid`. You can determine this path programmaticaly with [`session_save_path()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php), but can also be changed (if you have access to the destination path).
- The name of the session cookie/parameter (standard: `PHPSESSID`) is configured with `session.name` in php.ini. You can determine and change the session name with [`session_name()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php). This has to be done, before you call `session_start()`