# Step by step flow from session creation to accessing session value from server in PHP

Tags: php, session-cookies

i would like to know that when a session starts on server in PHP what actually happens SEQUENTIALLY on server and client side?

like when a page with some session values is accessed, will create a file on server first or it creates a cookie on client computer? and what if cookie is disabled on client machine?

Please let me know if someone has any comments on this.
Thanks!!

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954879/how-session-works

Answer (score 0):

**`Session`** can't be disabled on client machine unlike **`cookies`**.

Manual on [`Session`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php), [`Cookies`](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php) and [`Session vs Cookies`](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/10/1/0).