# PHP sessions only works second time?

Tags: php

Why will this only work the SECOND time I navigate to another page?

On page on:

```
session_start();
$a_var = $_POST["var"];

if (isset($_POST["var"])) {
$_SESSION['ses_var'] = $a_var;
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>relocate('http://www.mydomain.com/newfile.php');  </script>";
}
```

On page two:

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['ses_var'];
```

It's a part of a bigger login-system, but now I've simple tried to cut down the code to this, but it's still empty the first time I try to navigate to newfile.php!
If I go back and try again, then it gets my ses_var on newfile.php.

Please help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Session Works?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954879/how-session-works)

Answer (score 1):

You might be running into session-cookie problems. Please make sure the first page and second page are the exact same domain name. And check to see for example that page1 isn't `www.domain.com` while page2 is just `domain.com` without the `www.`

And if that is the case, you can even set session-cookie domain settings to allow for `*.domain.com`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sess_life_time = 21600; //in seconds
$sess_path = "/";
$sess_domain = ".you-site-name.com";
$sess_secure = true; // if you have secured session
$sess_httponly = true; // httponly flag

session_set_cookie_params($sess_life_time, $sess_path, $sess_domain, $sess_secure, $sess_httponly);
```