# Cakephp lose session when close browser and apache load balancer

Tags: apache, session, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

my site have config load balancer from https to http
and in my cource code /app/Config/core.php

```
    Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'cake',
    'timeout' => 4320,
    'checkAgent' => false,
    'cookieTimeout'=>0,
    'ini' => array(
      'session.cookie_secure' => false,
      'session.referer_check' =>false
   )
));
```

it's mean that session is store in /app/tmp/. and timeout 3days.
but when i open the browser(Chrome/IE) it create a session in folder app/tmp/
and I close the browser and open it again, it create a new file. So the old Session lose??

I've change to config defaults =>'php' but it's the same.

Can Anyone help me!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `Session.cookieTimeout` set to 0. Remove `Session.cookieTimeout` and it will default to `Session.timeout` value - 4320

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But this config is cookies session not a session.
and i've use config 'checkAgent' => false, for not check agent of browser each time open browser. But ir not work now.

Comment: Session.cookieTimeout - The number of minutes before the session cookie expires. If this is undefined, it will use the same value as Session.timeout - from CakePHP docs

Comment: But I don't care about session cookie. 
I just care about only session

Comment: A client-side cookie contains a reference to the server-side session and is required to find the users previous session data. You are deleting that cookie with a timeout value of 0. You are saying that the cookie lives for 0 minutes, and therefore losing the reference the server-side session data. Try commenting out `//'cookieTimeout'=>0,` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954879/how-session-works

Comment: Hi  Progredi,

I've changed the value of Session.cookieTimeout to 4320 = Session.timeout. It work ok now.
I don't know why, the last time, Ive set value Session.cookieTimeout 0, it work, but now it doesn't

Comment: Glad you got it working! Don't forget to mark answer useful :-)